# Git revert <commit_HashID> is not working on local and adding lines in code

Tags: git

My git status and latest 3 commits are as below

```
   user@computer:~/checks$ git status
   On branch master
   nothing to commit, working tree clean
   user@computer:~/checks$ git log -3
   commit a1905ee62cff9003f7f565ef4a664c6d9f646d80 (HEAD -> master)
   Author: 19mddil <mddilshadul98@gmail.com>
   Date:   Tue Jul 28 09:51:37 2020 +0600

        well more accurate

   commit 39574469dc4d70e93db1370627ba75cdc380876c
   Author: 19mddil <mddilshadul98@gmail.com>
   Date:   Tue Jul 28 09:49:15 2020 +0600

        well hello.py not only does hello printing now

   commit 9684b59596ca1d31db85a0c0b092b7053be1af6f
   Author: 19mddil <mddilshadul98@gmail.com>
   Date:   Tue Jul 28 09:37:01 2020 +0600

       added gitingore file and its notes
```

Now in hello.py I do two intentional mistakes in two commits in each deleting one variable respectively.
So,after that I run
`user@computer:~/checks$ git log -3`
which show like below,

```
   commit 7d9b1652f8959702aafe992995fe949808df2795 (HEAD -> master)
   Author: 19mddil <mddilshadul98@gmail.com>
   Date:   Tue Jul 28 15:48:16 2020 +0600

       intentional mistake two

   commit c3475c657f53e4e1dd8496f3487fd8c7050033d1
   Author: 19mddil <mddilshadul98@gmail.com>
   Date:   Tue Jul 28 15:47:19 2020 +0600

       intentional mistake one

   commit a1905ee62cff9003f7f565ef4a664c6d9f646d80
   Author: 19mddil <mddilshadul98@gmail.com>
   Date:   Tue Jul 28 09:51:37 2020 +0600

       well more accurate
```

So now I do not want these two intentional mistakes as I intend to do
`git revert a1905ee62cff9003f7f565ef4a664c6d9f646d80` to skip last two commits.
But it shows something like below,

```
    user@computer:~/checks$ git revert a1905ee62cff9003f7f565ef4a664c6d9f646d80
    error: could not revert a1905ee... well more accurate
    hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
    hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
    hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

I am having hard time finding my human error:(

And my code hello.py gets some weird lines too.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

    print("hello world")

    def sum(num1,num2):
        return num1>num2

    <<<<<<< HEAD #This is weird line number 1


    ======= #This is weird line number 2
    m = 5 #This variable was deleted in commit c3475c657f53e4e1dd8496f3487fd8c7050033d1
    n = 4.9 #This variable was deleted in commit 7d9b1652f8959702aafe992995fe949808df2795
    """ The two variables m and n come back but insert 3 weird lines in code """
    >>>>>>> parent of a1905ee... well more accurate ##This is weird line number 3
    if sum(m,n):
        print(f"{m} is greater than {n}")
    else :
        print(f"{m} is equal or less then {n}")
```

So I am really having hard time finding my human error:(

Answer (score 0):

Your commits have conflicts and you're not reverting the latest commit. Basically, you're reverting an older commit but newer commit have changes which conflict with the old commit.

If you want to revert to your commit (which looses all changes after the selected commit), use `reset` instead:

```
git reset --hard a1905ee62cff9003f7f565ef4a664c6d9f646d80
```

Comment: I know but as you said
I can not turn back to it without resetting hard(losing commits)? But despite my new file has changes my old files is accurate and I do not want those changes but keep them as commit,doesn't git allow it? what is the purpose of reverting after all?

Comment: @MohammedDilshad Well you can't revert to a previous version if newer versions modify what was reverted :)

Comment: I can work in a different branch, then merge both after resolving the conflict thus gives me the right to take the decision to keep the changes or not.